# Git repo grew after running repack

Tags: git, git-svn

We've been using Subversion and are considering moving to git. So I am very much a git illiterate. I used `git svn clone` to copy the svn history to git and my git folder was 3.1G. I followed some advice from several blogs to shrink it and ran:
`git repack -a d -f --window=100`
It processed 494,755 objects successfully but when I look at the disk size now it is using 3.7G. So what I thought would shrink it made it significantly larger. I tried running it again with 
`git repack -a d -f --window=250 --depth=250`
but no changes to the size. The `git prune` command also didn't appear to do anything. It took several days to clone this, so I would rather not start over. 

Is there any way to go back to the smaller size, or any ideas anyone has on why repack made it bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git-svn` is a good way if you have to copy a repo from SVN to git, but honestly, it is better to work natively in git. That said, I've used this before and [this is the best guide](http://www.markus-gattol.name/ws/scm.html#sec22) I found on the matter.

Really, you may want to play around with the revision history you are importing by using the `-r` option. Also I did an:

```
rm -r `find -type d -name .svn`
```

to remove all the .svn folders. I don't plan on commiting from git to svn, so that was good for me, but if you plan to use git locally and commit to your SVN repo, then you'll have to do a little more research on the best way to do that.

Also `git-gc` helps to compress objects. See if that helps reduce the size of your repo.

Git is great so I hope you find you like it and switch over.

Comment: We do have to continue using svn for now, so far I'm the only engineer switching, sort of the guinea pig to learn the system. `git gc` worked great! it took it down to 2.8G, exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks!

Comment: You can definitely use `git svn dcommit` to push your git commits to the svn repo. You can also keep your `.svn/` folders around so you can use svn commands if necessary (though this can get confusing). Just add `.svn/` to your `.gitignore` and then add `.git/` and `.gitignore` to your `svn:ignore` property.

Comment: Thanks for the advice MatrixFrog, for now I decided to have 2 separate source folders, one for git and one for svn, a lot more disk space, but that way I don't screw up anything for good :)